# Disproving that a plane is the union of countably many functions. Where is the fallacy?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

This question is inspired by the following statement: "The plane is the union of countably many functions y=f(x) iff Continuum Hypothesis holds."

At first glance it is easy to show that a plane is NOT a union of countably many functions y=f(x).

Proof: Lets study line x=0. Each function crosses x=0 in exactly one point. If we can cover x = 0 with countably many functions then we can as well enumerate all real numbers with countable many points, which contradicts Cantor's first uncountability theorem. Hence, there is at least one point that isn't covered. QED (?)

Contor would have published it, if it was this easy. What went wrong?

Comment: Cantor would have published what? The false statement that "The plane is the union of countably many functions $y=f(x)$"? Or the undecidable statement that "The plane is the union of countably many functions $y=f(x)$ if and only if the Continuum Hypothesis holds"? (--- this being undecidable because the first alternative is false and the second alternative is undecidable.)

Comment: What is your source for that false statement? The correct statement (equivalent to the continuum hypothesis) is "the plane is the union of countably many sets, each of which is either the graph of a function $y=f(x)$ or the graph of a function $x=f(y).$"

Comment: I think you mean to say "graph of functions" instead of "functions"

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki They're the same thing, unless you're a Bourbakist.

Comment: "Each function crosses x=0 in exactly one point. "  What?????  $f(x) = x^2 + 4$ never crosses.  $f(x) = \sin x$ crosses infinitely, and $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in \mathbb Q \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$ crosses uncountably many times.

Comment: @fleablood that's $y=0$, not $x=0$

Comment: @fleablood in at most 1 point.

Comment: Oh, oops.  Okay.  that makes sense.  But as bof points out that isn't the actual statement to be proven.

Comment: Got it. Original equivalence statement is incorrect. I can look at a union {{ y= f(x) },{ x=g(y)}}, remove strictly vertical functions g(y) = x0. We still have continuum of Xi, that aren't covered by vertical lines.  But it is unclear, what to do next. Thanks.

Comment: Reminds me of: CH iff there is a subset of the plane that has a countable intersection with each vertical line and its complement has a countable intersection with each horizontal line.  (To define it, well-order the reals and take the set of in-order pairs, every initial segment of a well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ is countable iff CH.)

Comment: Waclaw Sierpinski's *Hypothese du Continu* (forgive me, I don't have time to look up the alt codes for the diacriticals) lists a number of propositions equivalent to the continuum hypothesis, among them the proposition P$_2$ on p. 11: "The plane is a sum of a denumerable infinity of curves" (my translation Sierpinski's French) where a *curve* is the set of points $(x,y)$ satisfying an equation of the form $y=f(x)$ or $x=f(y)$ where $f$ is a function of a real variable.

Comment: @DanBrumleve Right, that's Sierpinski's Proposition P$_1$, and his Proposition P$_2$ (about covering the plane with countably many "curves" of the form $y=f(x)$ or $x=f(y)$) is a corollary of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must consider **two** sets of functions: y=f(x) and x=g(y). It is easy to prove that one set of functions wouldn't cover the plane. 
It is unclear whether two sets of functions can cover the plane.